# Tensor - define function while evaluating other one

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to define an error function looking like this: `e = (y(0) - 1)^2`.

My `y` function/tensor looks like this:

```
n = 10

w = tf.Variable(np.random.random((1, n)))
b = tf.Variable(np.random.random(n))
a = tf.Variable(np.random.random(n))
s = tf.placeholder("float64")
f = tf.nn.sigmoid(-s * w + b)

y_1 = tf.reduce_sum(a * f, axis=1)
```

I have read, that all the variables have to be declared before the session start.

I'd define the error function/tensor like this:

```
e = tf.reduce_sum((y_1[0].eval(feed_dict={s: 0}) - 1) ** 2)
```

But, I'm not able to use `eval()` method outside the session block.

So, how should I define the tensor containing `y_1(0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't evaluate y_1[0] if you want to use it inside the graph.  Why not just use

```
e = tf.reduce_sum((y_1[0]) - 1) ** 2)
```